# Modifying regex matches in replacements

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to match some strings in a text file with a regex, and then modify all places where the pattern is found. It's like a search and replace, but I'm trying to replace with a modified version of what was found (and I'm sure this has a name but I'm not familiar enough with it).

So I'm looking for strings that match `[a-z]_[a-z]` (e.g., `some_string`) and I want to replace it by removing the underscore and capitalizing the second lowercase word, essentially camel-casing it (`someString`).

Any pointers on how to do this (the tricky part is I don't really know how to even Google for this).

**Edit**

I tried to simplify the question a bit to make it more generic, but I'm also trying to do this only in the case where the match doesn't happen in quotes. That is, I don't want to match underscores in quotes (so, no match here: `"this_is_a_string"`...that should remain as is). I probably should have included this when I first made this post.

Comment: You want to look into back referencing. Create two or more regular expressions that together equal the first one and then you can use the back reference of one of them to modify it.

Comment: @jbrennan I believe doing it with native strings will be easier something like array words = indexOf('-').split;
words[1].charAt(1).upperCase;
words.join  ^^^psuedocode

Comment: @raam86 I thought about that, but I have another requirement where under_scores can only be matched if they're not in quotes, so the regex is a little more complicated than the one I showed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use a callback function with *gsub*, example:

```
"some_thing_good".gsub(/_([a-z])/) {|m| m[1].upcase}
```

To avoid strings inside double-quotes you can do that:

```
"\"look_at_me\" some_thing_good".gsub(/"[^"]+"|_[a-z]/) {|m| (m.length>2)? m : m[1].upcase }
```

The idea is to match them before and replace them by themselves. If i test the match length, i know immediatly which part of the alternation has been matched, since the second part contains only 2 characters and the first part at least 3 characters.

Comment: Aha, this works well. So what I didn't mention in my question is I also have to exclude instances that come between quotes. Do you know a good way to do this as well?

Comment: @jbrennan You can match them at first in an alternation and return them as it

Comment: can you elaborate on what that means? I'm not sure I understand.

Answer (score 1):

I think the better approach is to use parentheses to enclose patterns that you are interesting in.

In your case, I would use the following regular expression:

```
string.gsub(/(?<=[a-z])_([a-z]+)/) {|s| "#{s[1].upcase}#{s[2..-1]}"}
```

This regexp can be read in two parts, the first ask for string that starts with valid char and the second is followed by "_" and a sequence of valid chars.

Inside the block code, you can use Regexp.last_match and will return the MatchData where you can access each pattern inside the parentheses, ex:

```
string.gsub(/(?<=[a-z])_([a-z]+)/) do |s| 
  p Regexp.last_match.to_a # this will print all sub-patterns found
  "#{s[1].upcase}#{s[2..-1]}" # return formatted string
end
```

As you mentioned, you are not interesting in patterns inside quotes. I would use a regular expression inside other. The first one to remove quoted string and second one to search for patterns:

```
string.scan(/(\"[^\"]+\"|([^\"]+))/) do |s|
  next s[0] unless s[1] # skip quoted data
  # replace snake case to camel case
  s[1].gsub(/(?<=[a-z])_([a-z]+)/) {|s| "#{s[1].upcase}#{s[2..-1]}"}
end
```