# Regex but ignoring certain words

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm using a regex successfully, but perhaps a little *too* successfully, and I'd like to add some exceptions to it, certain words I don't want it to affect. (See my [previous question for some background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155739/modifying-regex-matches-in-replacements)...this solved the given issue, now I need to add exceptions).

So, in summary, what I need to do is:

1. Find a pattern like `[a-z]_[a-z]`, so words like `some_var` but not `_var`.
2. Ignore those matches found inside double quotes, so **not** `"this_file.jpg"`.
3. Ignore those matches in a given list of keywords, so **not** something like `size_t`, etc (I have a list of exceptions).

When I find a suitable match, I transform it to camelCase, essentially (`some_var` -> `someVar`) and this was successfully answered in the earlier question.

This is in Ruby and this is what I have so far for code:

```
exclusions = ["size_t", "other_t"]
replacement = text.gsub(/"[^"]+"|_[a-z]/) {|match| (match.length > 2)? match : match[1].upcase } # doesn't do any exclusions from my list, only handles the quoted case.
```

I'm kind of at a loss. I think I need some kind of negative lookahead but I'm not really sure how to do so (not super experienced with regular expressions).

**Samples**

Input:

```
this_var "that_var" size_t
```

Output:

```
thisVar "that_var" size_t
```

That is, things in quotes should be untouched, and things in my exclusion list should also remain untouched. Any other string that matches `[a-z]_[a-z]` should be changed.

Comment: Would be really helpful if you include sample input(s) and output(s) exactly.

Comment: You probably want to use at least 2 seperate regexes for this, especially for the part with the list of words.

Comment: A very crude way to exclude the data based on the exclusions list would be `%r{exclusions.join("|")}` which would generate the regex `/size_t|other_t/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookbehind `(?<=..)` to test that you have a letter before, and preserved words have a length greater than 2, thus just add them before in the alternation.

```
text.gsub(/"[^"]+"|size_t|(?<=[a-z])_[a-z]/) {|match| (match.length > 2)? match : match[1].upcase }
```

Note: a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html%E2%80%8E) (or a lookahead) is an assertion that just checks a subpattern but don't consume characters.

Note too, that `"[^"]"` can be replace by `"(?:[^"]+|(?<=\\)")+"` to allow escaped double quotes between double quotes if needed.

In fine, ruby regex engine supports [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html%E2%80%8E) and [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html%E2%80%8E). You can rewrite you expression like this for more performances:

```
/"[^"]++"|size_t|(?<=[a-z])_[a-z]/
```

or

```
/"(?>[^"]++|(?<=\\)")+"|size_t|(?<=[a-z])_[a-z]/
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know ruby but I can give an algorithm here.

Matching words without surrounding quotes can be achieved as follows (note: literal regex; do whatever is necessary in Ruby to make it into a readable regex):

```
(?<!")([a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*)(?!")
```

This will match forbidden keywords (such as `size_t` for instance) but then you can always have a list of forbidden keywords, and try and see if the captured group matches one of the forbidden words. From then on, it's job done.

Regex walkthrough:

```
(?<!")          # position where the preceding text is not a double quote
(               # start group
    [a-z]+      # one character among 'a' - 'z', one or more times, followed by
    (?:         # begin non capturing group
        _       # an underscore, followed by
        [a-z]+  # one character among 'a' - 'z', one or more times
    )           # end non capturing group
    *           # zero or more times, followed by
(?!")           # a position where what immediately follows is not a double quote
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to ask if there is a compelling reason to do this all in one regex? I don't mind complexity here if it is important. But if you think you will ever have to do more complex parsing, it may well be worth just breaking it up into several steps.  For example,

1. Match candidate words
2. Reject forbidden keywrods
3. Transform

My experience is also that once you start to try to do more sophisticated parsing, you might look into more sophisticated parsers than simplex regex.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this like this:

```
input.gsub /"?[a-z]+_[a-z]+"?/ do |match|
  if match[0] == '"' && match[-1] == '"' || blacklist.include?(match)
    match
  else
    match.gsub(/_[a-z]/) { |match| match[1].upcase }
  end
end
```

`blacklist` is an array of words you don't want replaced.

Test:

```
input = 'this_var "that_var" size_t'
blacklist = %w{size_t other_t}

output = input.gsub /"?[a-z]+_[a-z]+"?/ do |match|
  if match[0] == '"' && match[-1] == '"' || blacklist.include?(match)
    match
  else
    match.gsub(/_[a-z]/) { |match| match[1].upcase }
  end
end

puts output
```

Output:

```
thisVar "that_var" size_t
```